# Lightswitch - add/edit window - remove created by, etc

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

When you click on the add button in a lightswitch application, the default pop-up window will appear. Is there any way how to remove the by-default generated "Created","Created by", "Modified", "Modified By" lines? (Other than creating a custom add details window).

I am talking about these ones: 
[image: annoying lines]

I have found this link [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/822530b6-9811-46d2-ab32-0c9ef67d6194/ls-2013-sl-remove-created-by-modified-by-from-autogenerated-add-edit-dialogs?forum=lightswitch) where the person says something about the metadata. Is it the right way to go? If yes, how do I access the metadata and where exactly do I put that code?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and doing the app in C#.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who would be stuck with this as well in the future - you have to right-click on the table in the server part, select "open with" and select "Automatic Editor Selector (XML)". You have to then scroll to EntityProperty and add "" attribute to it, as described in the link I posted in the original question. Then save the XML and reload the project. This will hide these fields when adding a data to this table.

Make sure to back up your project before doing so in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to let you know what worked for me. I just brought up the table in "Server" view, selected the boarder, then went over to the properties, and unchecked the box marked "Enable Created/Modified properties" under "General". Sorry if that didn't work, I'm very new to Lightswitch myself!